# Gradient function on a matrix in Octave/MatLab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, octave, gradient, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement the gradient descent algorithm in Octave/Matlab. I'm at the point where I have this 201x201 matrix called `errors`, which I would assume corresponds to a 2 input variables function `f(x, y)`. The matrix gives a nice gradient image when displayed with `imagesc`, but I am confused as to when I calculate `[dx, dy] = gradient(errors)`. I obtain both `dx` and `dy` to be 2 dimensional matrices (201x201) instead of simple vectors. I would assume that, since we calculate the partial derivative in regards to x (resp. y), y (resp. x) so it would disappear from the result of the operation. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, although I feel like I have a good enough understanding of how the gradient of a function works. Thank you in advance for you answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient exists at a point. Your `gradient` expression is evaluating the (numerical) gradient at all 201x201 points.

So for example, the gradient of `errors` at the point `(3,4)` is the vector `[dx(3,4), dy(3,4)]`.

This example might help: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html#bvhqkfr Notice how the information returned by `gradient` is enough to plot the whole vector field of gradients.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I was dumb and ignored the obvious. I know what to do from now on. Thank you.